# How can i adjust the spacing between individual labels in the legend in R?

Tags: r, legend, boxplot

I am trying to adjust the spaces between individual labels in the legend so that I can see all 9 labels but unfortunately I was not successful. Here is my code to generate the boxplots

```
  # raw counts
  boxplot(log2(counts+1), col = col[as.integer(group)], las = 2,
        main = "Raw counts distribution", ylab = expression(log[2] ~ (raw ~ count + 1)))
  legend("top", levels(group), fill=col[1:nlevels(group)], horiz=TRUE)
  # norm counts
  boxplot(log2(norm.counts+1), col = col[as.integer(group)], las = 2,
        main = "Normalized counts distribution", ylab = expression(log[2] ~ (norm ~ count + 1)))
  legend("top", levels(group), fill=col[1:nlevels(group)], horiz=TRUE)
```

[image: original boxplot]

I even tried to include the `text.width` function like this

```
    # raw counts
  boxplot(log2(counts+1), col = col[as.integer(group)], las = 2,
        main = "Raw counts distribution", ylab = expression(log[2] ~ (raw ~ count + 1)))
  legend("top", levels(group), fill=col[1:nlevels(group)], text.width = 0.2, horiz=TRUE)
  # norm counts
  boxplot(log2(norm.counts+1), col = col[as.integer(group)], las = 2,
        main = "Normalized counts distribution", ylab = expression(log[2] ~ (norm ~ count + 1)))
  legend("top", levels(group), fill=col[1:nlevels(group)], text.width = 0.2, horiz=TRUE)
```

but that got worse.

[image: modified boxplot]

How can adjust the spaces to see all the labels?